# SQL Server Dynamic where clause query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a dynamic query I just to do with linq

```
from a in Customers
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)? true : a.FirstName == name) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(last)? true : a.LastName ==  last)
select a;
```

but now I need to do in on Stored Procedure and I don't want to concatenate for security reason and performance. The most close example I found is this query

```
declare @Name as varchar(100)
declare @GroupName as varchar(100)

set @Name = ''
set @GroupName = 'Manufacturing'

SELECT TOP (1000) [DepartmentID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[GroupName]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[HumanResources].[Department]
  where ([Name] = case 
                    when @Name is null or @Name = '' then null
                    else @Name
                end
        ) 
                and 
        (
        [GroupName] = case
                when @GroupName is null or @GroupName = '' then null
                else @GroupName
            end
        )
```

This almost works. I think this should be the answer but the where clause fails for obvious reason.

I would like the where clause could  produce '1=1' if the param "Name" or "GroupName" is null 
example

```
@Name = "Somename"
@GroupName  = null
where (Name = @Name) and (1 = 1)
--or
@Name = null
@GroupName  = "Somegruopname"
where (1 = 1) and (GroupName = @GroupName)
--
@Name = null
@GroupName  = null
where (1 = 1) and (1 = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want it to succeed if the variable is null or empty or a match, so I would just write that in your stored procedure.

```
WHERE (@FirstName is null OR @FirstName = '' OR [FirstName] = @FirstName) 
 AND (@LastName is null OR @LastName = '' OR [LastName] = @LastName)
```

Comment: i need (EXAMPLE) when the param FirstName = NULL  and LastName = 'BLA' then my first sentence should be True like  **WHERE (1) AND @LASTNAME = 'BLA'  **

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding something. If you pass @FirstName=NULL and @LastNAme='BLA' into a stored procedure with the conditions above, the first condition will evaluate to true and the second condition will evaluate to LastName='BLA'. How does the condition not meet your use case?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of this working. If both parameters are NULL, it returns all records. If both parameters are specified, it returns records that match both. If only one parameter is specified, it returns record that match the other. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe2fb/2

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
declare @Name as varchar(100)
declare @GroupName as varchar(100) = 'Manufacturing'


set @Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Name))
set @GroupName = 'Manufacturing'

SELECT TOP (1000) [DepartmentID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[GroupName]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2017].[HumanResources].[Department]
  where ([Name] = coalesce(@Name,'') = '' OR [Name] = @Name)
                and 
        ([GroupName] = coalesce(@GroupName, '') = '' OR [GroupName] = @GroupName)
```